# Can you eat alligator?

Tags: meat

I have heard of people eating alligator. But only southern people. I am from Ohio and don't know any place in Ohio that has alligator meat.

Another thing I am concerned about is that alligators have lots of microbes and some might be heat resistant. If that is the case than that could cause food poisoning or worse, ulcers.

So is it safe to eat alligator?

Comment: Mm. Fried alligator is some good eatin'

Comment: I've heard anecdotally that predators tend to have more parasites in them. However, we clearly eat predatory fish and poultry, so even if that is true I'm not so sure there is any credible science linking them to major health risks. People have been eating alligators and snakes for a long time, and I have never heard about them being dangerous. I especially haven't heard anything about heat resistant pathogens.

Comment: It tastes like chicken. I'm not kidding, it does! Really tender too

Comment: @GdD - tenderness depends on cooking it properly. I've had some that was ridiculously rubbery, like chewing on rubber bands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can and it is. Google ['menu alligator'](https://www.google.nl/search?q=menu+alligator) and you will find plenty of restaurants that actually have it on the menu, like [this one](http://www.neworleansrestaurants.com/mulates_cajun_restaurant/menu/), [this one](http://jacques-imos.com/jacques-imos-menu/) or [this one](http://www.huckfinnscafe.com/news/food-menu/).

I doubt that a restaurant would (be allowed to) have it on the menu if it's unsafe to eat.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. I wouldn't eat any wild-caught game on the that was cooked on the rare side (microbes and parasites are a problem with most wild stuff), but if it's thoroughly cooked you should be fine.

I've actually eaten it before, and not to belabor the cliche, but it actually does taste kinda like chicken. The texture is better than chicken though.

Comment: Yeah. I have heard that it tastes like a cross between fish and chicken. I like any fish, whether it is something my dad caught like the bass I had once or storebought. I like chicken also. So maybe I will like alligator when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the Cincinnati area, and there is a restaurant in Springfield OH that serves alligator.

http://www.pappadeaux.com/menu/

Comment: Yeah. I am in the Columbus area and there is only 1 restaurant there that I know of that serves alligator. That is Creole Kitchen which is about 14 miles away from where I am. That is very close. Usually to get alligator I would have to travel at least 100 if not 1000 miles.